# Zookeeper server concept

Tags: apache, apache-zookeeper

I am new to zookeeper and I learnt that zookeeper co-ordinates services such as leader election and others in an distributed application. When i started the zookeeper in replicated mode of 3 servers one becomes leader and others are followers. I want to know whether leader election is  implemented in zookeeper server also

Answer (score 1):

Yes - Zookeeper has its own internal [leader election algorithm](http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.3.5/zookeeperInternals.html#sc_leaderElection).   This is separate from any leader election algorithms implemented using the Zookeeper API.